# WP Login redirect_to being completely ignored? (no filter, separate domain)

Tags: wordpress

I have a link on a site which is supposed to send the user to the login page for a separate WP site (at a different sub-domain), after which they will be returned to the page they originally came from. The redirect url is formed in javascript and looks roughly like:

```
"MyWPDomain/wp-login.php?redirect_to=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)
```

I've also tried it with the simpler `encodeURI()` function as well, no luck.

When I try to login, it currently just sends me to the admin page instead of the url encoded in the query string of the page.

I don't have sufficient access to the WP site's backend to add new code, only dashboard access (I'm not the one managing the WP site, just working with them), so afaik I can't rely on the `add_filter` solutions that I've seen on most other similar posts.

Is this even possible to redirect at all without a filter? Is it generally possible to redirect from the login page to a separate domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing any URL to be passed in as a redirect presents a security vulnerability. A URL can appear to be site A and then take the user to malicious site B once the redirect fires.

The `redirect_to` query parameter is run through `wp_safe_redirect()` which will only allow redirects to permitted hosts. If you want to redirect the user to an external domain, it won't be allowed by default.

The only way to resolve that would be to filter `allowed_redirect_hosts`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/allowed_redirect_hosts/

Example:

```
function wpse_add_external_domain_to_allowed_hosts( $hosts ) {
    $hosts[] = 'example.com';
    return $hosts;
}
add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts', 'wpse_add_external_domain_to_allowed_hosts' );
```

As you noted in your original post however you don't have sufficient permissions to implement such code. If you don't have access to implement a filter, you won't be able to alter the redirect behaviour.

Comment: This is what I suspected. I'll have to ask to see how hard it would be to do this.  Does that segment of code (or a similar one) just go in the theme file? In a custom plugin? I'd like to be as explicit as I can when I ask the other person if they can do this and I'm not very familiar with WP backend stuff.

Comment: Also, I edited the post to reflect it, but the other site is at a different sub domain of the SAME root domain, I'm not sure if that would influence the `allowed_redirect_hosts`

Comment: You'd want to do something like this in a custom plugin. I'll often create a helpers plugin that I fill with miscellaneous functionality that doesn't belong in the theme.

Comment: We actually already have a custom plugin for interfacing between the WP site and our app for something completely separate. I, not being very familiar with everything, just didn't even assume that would have the ability to do this behavior since our existing use is completely different. This is good news, thanks!